# Reuse subquery result in WHERE-Clause for INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 
i would like to save the result of a subquery to reuse it in a following subquery.
Is this possible?
What is best practice to do this? (I am very new to SQL)

My query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
(
[a]
,[b]
)
SELECT 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 MAT_WS_ID  
   FROM #TempTableX AS X_ALIAS 
   WHERE OUTERBASETABLE.LT_ALL_MATERIAL = X_ALIAS.MAT_RM_NAME
)  
,(
    SELECT TOP 1 MAT_WS_NAME
    FROM #TempTableY AS Y_ALIAS
    WHERE Y_ALIAS.MAT_WS_ID = MAT_WS_ID 
    --( 
        --SELECT TOP 1 MAT_WS_ID  
        --FROM #TempTableX AS X_ALIAS 
        --WHERE OUTERBASETABLE.LT_ALL_MATERIAL = X_ALIAS.MAT_RM_NAME
    --)
) 
FROM [dbo].[LASERTECHNO]  AS OUTERBASETABLE
```

My question is:

Is this correct what i did.
I replaced the second SELECT Statement in the WHERE-Clause for [b] (which is commented out and exactly the same as for [a]), with the result of the first SELECT Statement of [a] (=MAT_WS_ID).
It seems to give the right results.
But i dont understand why!

I mean MAT_WS_ID is part of both temporary tables X_ALIAS and Y_ALIAS.
So in the SELECT statement for [b], in the scope of the [b]-select-query, MAT_WS_ID could only be known from the Y_ALIAS table. (Or am i wrong, i am more a C++, maybe the scope things in SQL and C++ are totally different)

I just wannt to know what is the best way in SQL Server to reuse an scalar select result.
Or should i just dont care and copy the select for every column and the sql server optimizes it by its own?

Comment: you should always join onto a table and remove inner selects for better performance

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be `outer apply`:

```
SELECT  mat.MAT_WS_ID
,       (
        SELECT TOP 1 MAT_WS_NAME
        FROM #TempTableY AS Y_ALIAS
        WHERE Y_ALIAS.MAT_WS_ID = mat.MAT_WS_ID  
        ) 
FROM    [dbo].[LASERTECHNO]  AS OUTERBASETABLE
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 MAT_WS_ID  
        FROM    #TempTableX AS X_ALIAS 
        WHERE   OUTERBASETABLE.LT_ALL_MATERIAL = X_ALIAS.MAT_RM_NAME
        ) as mat
```

Comment: And if there are more than one of this similar statements?

Comment: That would depend on the kind of similarity.  One option is mulitple `outer apply`, but there are other options, like [`with`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could rank rows in `#TempTableX` and `#TempTableY` partitioning them by `MAT_RM_NAME` in the former and by `MAT_WS_ID` in the latter, then use normal joins with filtering by `rownum = 1` in both tables (`rownum` being the column containing the ranking numbers in each of the two tables):

```
WITH x_ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MAT_RM_NAME ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM #TempTableX
),
y_ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MAT_WS_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM #TempTableY
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (a, b)
SELECT
  x.MAT_WS_ID,
  y.MAT_WS_NAME
FROM dbo.LASERTECHNO t
  LEFT JOIN x_ranked x ON t.LT_ALL_MATERIAL = x.MAT_RM_NAME AND x.rownum = 1
  LEFT JOIN y_ranked y ON x.MAT_WS_ID       = y.MAT_WS_ID   AND y.rownum = 1
;
```

The `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` bit is a trick to specify an indeterminate ordering, which, accordingly, would result in indeterminate `rownum = 1` rows picked by the query. That is to more or less duplicate your `TOP 1` without an explicit order, but I would recommend you to specify a more sensible `ORDER BY` clause to make the results more predictable.